# Are queries to athena considered when viewing S3 Analytics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, data-warehouse, amazon-athena

I have several athena databases and tables partitioned by date. I would like to move the underlying S3 buckets to different storage classes depending on how often these tables are queried. I am considering enabling S3 Storage Class Analysis on the underlying buckets of these tables. I wanted to know if queries to Athena on these tables / partitions will show up when viewing the data access pattern of the underlying S3 buckets using Amazon S3 Analytics. For example if I query an athena table 10 times and view the underlying S3 bucket's analytics, will it show that I viewed the S3 bucket 10 times?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, queries from Athena will be considered in the storage class analysis. Behind the scenes Athena makes regular `LIST` and `GET` operations against your S3 buckets.

You can verify this either by enabling logging in S3, or enabling object level logging for the bucket in CloudTrail.

Comment: Can you give some form of documentation where you see that Athena makes LIST and GET operations to S3?  I couldnt find it anywhere

Comment: I'm not sure there is any documentation describing Athena at that low level. Athena is a managed service built on Presto, which in turn uses the filesystem implementation for S3 from Hadoop, which does LIST and GET operations. There's really no other way that it could do it. If you want to verify it use S3 logging or CloudTrail. Neither Athena, nor any other AWS service that I know of, has any back-channel access to S3, they use it like you or I would.

Answer (score 0):

For example you configured S3 analytics for bucket1, bucket2 and exported this data to bucket3 then querying bucket3 to analyse this data will not have any impact by Athena queries.

If you also configured analytics for bucket3 and export it the same bucket i.e, bucket3 then you should see the access patterns created by Athena.

It's better to export the data to totally different s3 bucket than what you have enabled s3 analytics on.This will keep things simple and will make it easy for you when you want to change the storage class.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the response. I am not sure I fully understand. "If I query an athena table 10 times and view the underlying S3 bucket's analytics, will it show that I viewed the S3 bucket 10 times?" Is this the case?

Comment: which bucket did you exported this S3 Analytics data to? Did you enabled analytics on this bucket too ? If yes then it will show up. otherwise it will not